# Linking GUI to Main in Java

Tags: java, swing, class, user-interface

I'm very new to Java and OOP in general and I want to call my GUI class from my Main class which will be the start point for my program.

This should be pretty simple but any help will be appreciated

GUIForm1 Code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GUIForm1 {

private JPanel MainPanel;
private JPanel MenuPanel;
Private JPanel AnimationPanel;
private JButton greenTrail;
private JButton purpleTrail;
private JSeparator animationMenuDivider;
private JSlider rangeSlider;
//more components

public GUIForm1() {


   JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUIForm1");
    frame.setContentPane(new GUIForm1().MainPanel);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

   }
}
```

Main Class Code:

```
public class ProjectileSim {

public static void main(String[] args){
    GUIForm1 gui = new GUIForm1();

}
}
```

Comment: So, what is the problem you are having??

Comment: Looks like you called every piece of code that can be called on GUIForm1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is good. Your main class instantiation of the GUIForm class is also correct. The reason why you are having an issue is here:

---

```
 frame.setContentPane(new GUIForm1().MainPanel);
```

---

That is your issue in the code. You are trying to call the constructor of your class within your class to set a MainPanel that is non-existent.

If you are using NetBeans (Or any IDE) it is simple enough for you to just drag a JPanel onto your GUI and then you can set your frames content frame to that (for example):

---

```
frame.setContentPane(myNewJPanel);
```

---

Give it a go. Comment out the line where you are setting your contentframe and see what I mean.

(this is how you comment out by the way :

```
//frame.setContentPane(new GUIForm1().MainPanel);
```

You just insert 2 forward slashes in front of the line that you do not want to be executed.

All the best. Let me know of the outcome.

Comment: That worked thanks! I just needed to remove the "new GUIForm1()." part. This has cleared quite a bit up for me

Comment: Perfect, glad I could help :) Good luck further.

Answer (score 0):

add text Jfield or JButton or change the colour of the panel you feel somthing new.
And the main method is must in java which should exist in public classs.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is very general. I would advise you to go through https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/start/index.html at the beginning.

But, what you should do in order to get any visible result at all would be:

```
public GUIForm1() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUIForm1");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Normally you should initialize the GUI objects (like JButtons, JFrame etc.) and then add them to the Content Pane, and after that set everything to visible. But go through the tutorials, since they cover all the basics.